# Holding keys down on my laptop keyboard does not work, only single press works

Tags: 12.04, keyboard

When I press any key on my Toshiba Satellite pro L 300 laptop keyboard, the single key press works, but if I hold down the key, I don't get anything. When I hold a key down, I want the same character to be typed over and over until I release the key.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. How can I configure this the way I want?

Answer (score 3):

Referring to [this post](http://www.khattam.info/solved-key-repeat-stopped-working-problem-in-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx-alpha-2-2010-01-31.html), go to your Keyboard Preferences section, ensure the "Key presses repeat when key is held down" option is checked and adjust the delay and speed sliders which should trigger the functionality to come back.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the [solution from ljs.dev](https://askubuntu.com/a/308411/581818), in Ubuntu 20.04 this fix translates to switching the **Repeat Keys** setting off and then back on. **Repeat Keys** is found in **Settings > Universal Access** under the **Typing** section.

Comment: Can confirm this worked on 20.04.6 LTS. Repeat Keys was already on, but switching it off and back on again solved the issue.